# Create new array from json in Python

Tags: python, arrays

If you have a multilevel, nested json from url:

```
import json
import urllib.request

data = urllib.request.urlopen("https://url").read()
output = json.loads(data)

for each in output['toplevel']:
    Key = each['Key']
    Value = each['Value']

    string = {Key:Value}

    print(dict(new_context = string))
```

This return:

```
{'new_context': {'the_Key1': 'the_Value1'}}
{'new_context': {'the_Key2': 'the_Value2'}}
{'new_context': {'the_Key3': 'the_Value3'}}
```

What i want:

```
{'new_context': {'the_Key1': 'the_Value1', 'the_Key2': 'the_Value2', 'the_Key3': 'the_Value3'}}
```

Comment: just look up how to a) create an empty dictionary, b) add elements to it. Right now you are making new dictionaries in each loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go :

```
import json
import urllib.request

data = urllib.request.urlopen("https://url").read()
output = json.loads(data)

result = {"new_context": {}}

for each in output['toplevel']:

    result["new_context"][each['Key']] = each['Value']

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d={}
keys=['1','2','3']
vals=['one','two', 'three']

for i in range(3):
    d[keys[i]]=vals[i]

print(d)
```

output:

```
{'1': 'one', '2': 'two', '3': 'three'}
```